# Two redirect in program

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I try write a command interpreter in C. I must create dwo and three redirects (e.g. `ls | grep ^d | wc -l` and `ls -ps | grep / | pr -3 | more`)

I have code to operate one redirects

```
    if(k==1)
{
  int pfds[2];
  pipe(pfds);
  child_pid = fork();
  if(child_pid==0)
  {       
    close(1);       
        dup(pfds[1]);   
        close(pfds[0]); 
        execlp(arg1[0], *arg1, NULL);
  }
  else 
  {
        close(0);      
        dup(pfds[0]);
        close(pfds[1]); 
        execlp(arg2[0], *arg2, NULL);
  }     
}
```

My question is how make two and three redirects using `pipe` and `fork`?

I try do this using only one pipe but this in not work.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to create as many `pipe` variables as there are "diversion".
then create a list of commands.

if you want parent process leave,you would fork a process for each command. otherwise one less.

for the very first command, `dup` or 'dup2` only for STDOUT.

and for the very last command `dup` or 'dup2` only for STDIN.

for the rest, `dup` or 'dup2` for STDIN and STDOUT both.

you can do this with a for loop from 2nd to second-last.

For Example:
shell $> cat file.txt | grep 'pattern1|pattern2' | grep 'pattern1' | wc -l

I am assuming you are not using parent process for `exec`
So, you would create a list/array/vector of commands. list would have all 4 commands.
create 4 pipes for each commands in parent process itself.

run a loop for 4 iteration, each for a command.

- fork one process.
- if parent process, continue.
- else(child)

  - dup/dup2 only STDOUT for first command(`cat`).
  - dup/dup2 only STDIN for last command(`wc -l`).
  - dup/dup2 both STDIN and STDOUT otherwise.
  - then run `exec`.

CHEERS :)

Comment: Look inside the source code of some existing shell, like [sash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) or [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)